# jQuery Dialog Widget using

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made this function, which change my dialog title. But I don't know, is it right way to do it. I want that, when you do this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, title: n });
```

then title - *"yyy"*, change to *"xxxyyy"*. But I can't figure it out, how to do it?

```
<div id="dialog" style="display: none;">hello</div>
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
<button id="change"> Change name </button>
<script>
    var n = 'Basic Title';
    var x = '';
    var $dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, title: n });
    $("#opener").click(function() { $dialog.dialog("open"); });
    $("#change").click(function() {
        var x = prompt("New title");

        if (x === n){
            var $dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen: false, title: n});
        } else {
            var $dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen: false, title: "xxx" + x});
        }

        $dialog.dialog("open");
    });
</script>
```

SO, i added      "xxx" +       in my jQuery UI:

```
_title: function( title ) {
if ( !this.options.title ) {
title.html("&#160;");
}
title.text( "xxx" + this.options.title );
},
```

But i want to add it there, without editing default jQuery UI.
I try to do it in another script file, i try to use this 
    $.getScript("js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js", function( ){
so i can now modify jQuery code from another place, but i cant figure out how to edit it. If i just copy paste that function, it wont work :(

This is wat i needed :)

```
$.widget("ui.dialog", $.extend({}, $.ui.dialog.prototype, {
_title: function (title) {
if (!this.options.title) {    
title.html("&#160;");
}
title.html("xxx" + this.options.title);
}
}));
```

Comment: the title can be set with $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "title", "Dialog Title" );

Comment: and get the existing title `var title = $("#dialog").dialog( "option", "title" );` See http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-title

Comment: Can you please write it in code? I put it in code but it doesn't work. I am beginner, so maybe i have some syntax mistakes. I will be very thanksfull.

Comment: I suggest you don't modify the jquery source. If you need customization look to writing a [jQuery plug-in](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/) or just keep your additions in a separate source file.

Comment: Your latest edit changes the scope and nature of your original question. You should post your latest edit as a new question on another post -- it is far more likely to be seen and recieve help from others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is very close but you don't need to create new dialogs for title changes.

```
$("#change").click(function () {
    var x = prompt("New title");
    var title = $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title");  // get existing title

    if (x != n) {
        $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", title + "" + x);  // set new title
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LbTxa/1/

Comment: And is there a way, to declare this in default jQuery UI? So i have this function in default, and don't need to write a new script for it?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Much of this example is jQuery UI. What isn't jQuery UI here is a specific to your use case. The code above can be written so it's more reusable in your project but I think that could be posted as a new question.